# Blazor - Base Render in an inherited component doesn't use overridden methods

Tags: inheritance, razor, blazor

I'm trying to make a Blazor component that I will then specialize and override some methods.

Base Component "ZoomList":

```
@inherits ComponentBase
<div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @foreach (var str in Headers())
                {
                    <th>@str</th>
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in items)
            {
                <tr>
                    @foreach (var str in Rows(item))
                    {
                        <td>@str</td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<Object> items { get; set; }

    protected virtual List<string> Rows(Object item) { return new List<string>() { "Placeholder" }; }
    protected virtual List<string> Headers() { return new List<string>() { "Placeholder" }; }
}
```

Derivated component "ZoomCampaign":

```
@inherits ZoomList
@using MyNamespace.Model

@{
    this.BuildRenderTree(__builder);
}

@code {

    protected override List<string> Rows(Object item)
    {
        Campaign camp = item as Campaign;
        return new List<string>() {
            camp.Id.ToString(),
            camp.Nom
        };
    }

    protected override List<string> Headers()
    {
        return new List<string>() { "#", "Name" };
    }
}
```

ZoomCampaign is then called from another page.
But this.BuildRenderTree(__builder) doesn't use the overridden methods but is using the base methods.
=> My html array is contains the "Placeholder" text, not the text defined in override methods "Rows" and "Headers" from ZoomCampaign.

What am I missing ? How can I change it so that override methods are the ones that are used during rendering ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer, this is not how components work - specifically this code should be removed from ZoomCampaign:

```
@{
    this.BuildRenderTree(__builder);
}
```

You can look at the generated code (`ZoomCapaign.razor.g.cs`) to see what is going wrong.

When you put that code in the `markup` of a `razor component`, you are basically saying "hey, when you come to render ZoomCampaign, please render ZoomCapaign"

This is worse than redundant (ZoomCapaign is already being rendered) as it has introduced a bug.

**Solution**

Remove the code mentioned above.
Additionally, your ZoomCapaign component does not use any Razor features and can be implemented in a simpler, cleaner, (less prone to this kind of error) way as a `csharp` file `ZoomCampaign.cs` instead.

Try it here : https://blazorrepl.com/repl/QvkQuMOX35G4Syyg08
_I did not override `Rows` in this sample because I don't have the model, but you can see the `Headers` override is working.

Answer (score 2):

The answers above are correct, but probably don't make it that clear what's happening.

You have a Razor markup defined component called `ZoomList`.  When this gets built your markup is turned into `RenderTreeBuilder` code (ZoomList.razor.g.cs in the obj build folder).

You then define `ZoomCampaign` which inherits from `ZoomList`.  However, you overload the inherited Razor code by calling `this.BuildRenderTree(__builder);` which builds an empty component - there's no body to the method.

Remove

```
@{
    this.BuildRenderTree(__builder);
}
```

and the child component renders the parent's Razor markup.

FYI, a classic Hello World `BuildRenderTree` looks like this:

```
protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
{
   builder.OpenElement(0, "div";
   builder.AddContent(1, "Hello World");
   builder.CloseElement();
}
```

Put it in the code section of `ZoomCampaign` and see what you get.

Note that Microsoft's documentation suggests you don't write you own RenderTree code!

Answer (score 1):

I think components are not intended to be used that way. Though, I can't find a good sounding explanation why your scenario is not supported.

I would split the problem into two distinct areas. First, create a table component.

**TableComponent**

```
<div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @foreach (var str in Headers)
                {
                    <th>@str</th>
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                <tr>
                    @foreach (var str in Rows(item))
                    {
                        <td>@str</td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<Object> Items { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public List<String> Headers { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Func<Object, List<String>> RowGetter { get; set; }

    protected virtual List<string> Rows(Object item) => RowGetter?.Invoke(item);

}
```

I've changed your method `Headers()` to a property `Headers` and introduced a `Func<Object,List<String>>` as property, to get the items based on the row. Both are parameters so that other components could bind them.

This component can be used in your `ZoomList` component like

```
<h3>ZoomList</h3>

<Table Items="items" Headers="Headers()" RowGetter="Rows" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<Object> items { get; set; }

    protected virtual List<string> Rows(Object item) { return new List<string>() { "Placeholder" }; }
    protected virtual List<string> Headers() { return new List<string>() { "Placeholder" }; }
}
```

And in your `ZoomCampaign` it could be something like

**ZoomCampaign.razor**

```
@inherits ZoomList

<Table Items="items" Headers="Headers()" RowGetter="Rows" />

@code {

    protected override List<string> Rows(Object item)
    {
        Campaign camp = item as Campaign;
        return new List<string>() {
            camp.Id.ToString(),
            camp.Nom
        };
    }

    protected override List<string> Headers()
    {
        return new List<string>() { "#", "Name" };
    }
}
```

Or you could create this component without its own UI. In this case, you would need to create a .cs and not a .razor file.

**ZoomCampaign.cs**

```
public class ZoomCampaign : ZoomList
{
    protected override List<string> Rows(Object item)
    {
        Campaign camp = item as Campaign;
        return new List<string>() {
        camp.Id.ToString(),
        camp.Nom
    };
    }

    protected override List<string> Headers()
    {
        return new List<string>() { "#", "Name" };
    }
}
```

Another approach would be to invest more thought into the `Table` component. You could make it generic, and find ways to pass "parsing" logic into the table for instance how to split a `Campaign` into columns, etc. In that case, you wouldn't need the inheritance feature.